# TypeError: to_excel() missing 1 required positional argument - despite using excel writer

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd, writer

I've been having trouble saving to excel using pandas with the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/Colleen/Documents/Non-online code/kit_names.py", line 36, in save_sheet_names
pd.DataFrame.to_excel(writer)
```

TypeError: to_excel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'excel_writer'
 here

After having typed this:

```
    df =pd.DataFrame(arr)
y=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
new_path = r"C:\Users\Colleen\Documents\\"+y
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
pd.DataFrame.to_excel(writer)
```

Seemingly the writer is being used but evidently i have gone wrong somewhere! (I apologise if this is an obvious question as i am still getting my head around pandas)

Pycharm is signalling a minor error which may be what is causing this however i don't understand what it means in truth and struggled to find a mention online.

> passing pandas.io.excel.excelwriter instead of pandas.core.frame.dataframe. Is this intentional?

What do i need to do to fix this please?

Comment: Whats the value of y? You need your writer path to be a filename (.xls or xlsx)

Comment: y is simply the name of the file i'm accessing at the time - it does contain the .xlsx at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change the `to_excel()` function to be caled on `df`

```
df =pd.DataFrame(arr)
y=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
new_path = r"C:\Users\Colleen\Documents\\"+y
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer)
```