# to_excel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'excel_writer' at my function

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm getting an error inside my function while I'm trying to convert a `.csv` file to excel. This function has the goal of able the user to download a CSV file at my streamlit app, however, I tried to change the moment him pick the csv file and convert it to excel with `object_to_download = object_to_download.to_excel()` but didn't work as expected.

The problem where i think it's:

```
elif isinstance(object_to_download, pd.DataFrame):
        object_to_download = object_to_download.to_excel()
```

Here is the whole function: https://gist.github.com/feliperoque/7d288813a2d9bc82143c497b2788ac3d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597773/typeerror-to-excel-missing-1-required-positional-argument-despite-using-exc Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, i did see this post but didn't worked...

Comment: If you can provide the error trackback, it would help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597773/typeerror-to-excel-missing-1-required-positional-argument-despite-using-exc Does this helps you

Comment: this is an issue with `pandas` not `streamlit`

Answer (score 0):

`.to_excel` takes  an argument `file name`

You have not given it, hence it raises the error.

The syntax is `df.to_excel('fileName')`.

Comment: right, but i did pass the file. When the script runs he get inside at  `tmp_download_link = download_button(cg_result_dataframe, f'cg_result_dataframe.xlsx', button_text='Donwload Cg Dataframe ')` where **cg_result_dataframe** is the dataframe i want to be downloaded. I did also change the extension of this file to xlsx instead of csv (which was before)

Comment: Here `fileName` is the name by which the exported file will be stored.
You can also give full path where you want to save the file as
`df.to_excel(r'Path where the exported excel file will be stored\File Name.xlsx')`
@FelipeRoque

Comment: i tried to put the path like `object_to_download = object_to_download.to_excel(r'C:/Donwloads', engine='xlsxwriter')` but returned the error **[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Donwloads'** any clue?

Comment: since i don't know the User name of the another guy who gonna use my app at streamlit, how might i fix this?

Comment: You missed the file name:

try this:`object_to_download = object_to_download.to_excel(r'C:/Donwloads/downloded.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`

@FelipeRoque