# Send a .xlsx via python

Tags: python, excel, smtp

I can send mail with a csv with this code:

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def send_email(send_to, subject, df):
    send_from = "xxx.xxx@hotmail.fr"
    password = "xxx"
    message = """\
    <p><strong>This is a test email&nbsp;</strong></p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p><strong>Greetings&nbsp;</strong><br><strong>Alexandre&nbsp;</strong></p>
    """

    multipart = MIMEMultipart()
    multipart["From"] = send_from
    multipart["To"] = send_to
    multipart["Subject"] = subject  
    attachment = MIMEApplication(df.to_csv())
    attachment["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=" {}"'.format(f"{subject}.csv")
    multipart.attach(attachment)
    multipart.attach(MIMEText(message, "html"))
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(multipart["From"], password)
    server.sendmail(multipart["From"], multipart["To"], multipart.as_string())
    server.quit()
        
send_email("xxx.xxx@hotmail.fr", "Covid-19 data per country", ListeProjetsCodeNovaMergefinal)
```

But if a replace df.to_csv() with df.to_excel() and .csv with .xlsx i have an error:

**TypeError: to_excel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'excel_writer'**

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: to\_excel() missing 1 required positional argument - despite using excel writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597773/typeerror-to-excel-missing-1-required-positional-argument-despite-using-exc)

Comment: No i am already in df.to_excel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a single object to an Excel .xlsx file it is only necessary to specify a target file name.

```
# storing into the excel file
data.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Yes I know but that's doesn't works here. I don't know why it's works with to_csv().

Comment: @Rocheteau as the doc says: `path_or_buf` parameter could be None, which makes the result is returned as a string. This doesn’t happen when we use `to_excel()`

Comment: Ok thanks in fact I can't used this code for excel. To bad.

Comment: hope I helped out 